# Is there a way to trigger the pipeline when manually creating a release?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

I am currently creating a gitlab pipeline in a 3 System environment (dev, qas, prd). I decided to use a trunk based pipeline where my main branch is my trunk and from there everything else is supplemented. Since I also want the 3 stages to be separat from each other and only allow certain members to deploy something to prd I thought of a pipeline like the following:

- DEV: A developer should be able to push code no matter what and how. The only thing which matters is that the code can be build and is correctly tested
- QAS: Here I want to know which version is currently present, therefore I want to use tags in gitlab.
- PRD: I only want certain members to be able to push to prd and also want a history, release notes and so on to be published. Therefore I want to use the release mechanism in gitlab to deploy everything to prd.

Therefore I created a pipeline looking something like the following:

```
stages:
    - build
    - test
    - deployDEV
    - deployQAS
    - deployPRD

build: 
    stage: build 
    # build everything

test: 
    stage: test
    # test everything

deployDEV: 
    stage: deployDEV 
    rules: 
        - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH' 
    script: 
       # deploy code to DEV 

deployQAS: 
    stage: deployQAS
    rules: 
       - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG && $CI_DEPLOY_FREEZE == null'
         when: manual
    script: 
      # deploy QAS 

deployPRD: 
    stage: deployPRD
    rules: 
      - if % new Release is created manually trigger this step % # currently not working
    script: 
      #deploy PRD
```

As you can see in my script above I am not able to push the code to production since the pipeline is not triggered when creating a release manually. Therefore I wanted to know if this is the default case or if I have missed something in the documentation?
I think it would be really great if this is possible, because then I would be able to test all my versions in qas environment and if one is the one to be released then I would simply make a new release with this version which then gets deployed.

What I already tried was going trough the documentation here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/. There you can only create releases but not that these releases trigger a pipeline

Comment: Would it be potentially simpler to generate the release as part of a deploy job in the .gitlab-ci.yml?

Comment: I also thought of that but if I only add the release as a part of the deployPRD job for example, I still would have pipelines in the queue for the production environment, since the release does not trigger the pipeline again. Or am I missing here something?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand but I can describe how I've setup my pipelines for a similar test/stage/prod deployment setup. I have a single Deploy stage with separate jobs specific to each type of deployment that have rules linked to commits to specific branches in a gitflow like setup (commit or merge to dev branch = deploy to dev, release branch = deploy to stage, main branch = deploy to prod). The deploy job for stage and prod also trigger release jobs. Stage release adds "rc" for release candidate and prod releases the final package. Both pick up the version number from tags.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar requirement and have been looking for a solution for that as well.

According to my research this is not possible via `rules`. In Gitlab there are different [types of pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/#types-of-pipelines). Here there are only very limited possibilities to control a pipeline by events within Gitlab. Here it would be desirable to have this as flexible as in GitHub with [Events that trigger workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#release).

I was able to solve my requirement with the webhooks from Gitlab as follows.

This is done by first creating a [trigger token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#trigger-a-pipeline) for the project whose pipeline is to be executed.

Here then also a URL is offered, which can be used over a Webhook. Unfortunately, it is also necessary to specify a token here. See [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#use-a-webhook).

Now a webhook can be set up for the project that should trigger the pipeline. Here exists a [Release event](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhook_events.html#release-events) which is fired when a Github release is created or modified.

I'm not very happy with the solution, but haven't found a better way yet.